# Amazon S3 POST api, and signing a policy with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cryptography

I'm trying to get an built that allows users to upload a file directly to my Amazon S3 bucket, from a NodeJS powered website. It seems the only tutorials out there, other than **[the actual amazon docs for this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html)** are all very out of date.

I've been following **[this tutorial](http://blog.tcs.de/post-file-to-s3-using-node/)**, for the basic info, but again it's out dated. It doesn't have the method calls to `crypto` correct, as it tries to pass a raw JavaScript object to the `update` method, which throws an error because it's not a string or buffer.

I've also been looking at the source for **[the knox npm package](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/blob/master/lib/auth.js)**. It doesn't have POST support built in - which I totally understand, because it's the browser doing the POST once it has the right fields. Knox does appear to have the right code to sign a policy, and I've tried to get my code working based on this... but again to no avail.

Here is what I've come up with, for code. It produces a base64 encoded policy, and it creates a signature... but it's the wrong signature according to Amazon, when I try to do a file upload.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var config = require("../../amazonConfig.json");

exports.createS3Policy = function(callback) {
  var date = new Date();

  var s3Policy = {
    "expiration": "2014-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
    "conditions": [
      {"acl": "public-read"}, 
      ["content-length-range", 0, 2147483648],
      {"bucket": "signalleaf"}, 
      ["starts-with", "$Cache-Control", ""],
      ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
      ["starts-with", "$Content-Disposition", ""],
      ["starts-with", "$Content-Encoding", ""],
      ["starts-with", "$Expires", ""],
      ["starts-with", "$key", "/myfolder/"], 
      {"success_action_redirect": "http://example.com/uploadsuccess"},
    ]
  };

  var stringPolicy = JSON.stringify(s3Policy).toString("utf-8");
  var buffer = Buffer(stringPolicy, "utf-8");

  var encoded = buffer.toString("base64");
  var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha1", config.secretKey)
    .update(new Buffer(stringPolicy, "utf-8")).digest("base64");


  var s3Credentials = {
    s3PolicyBase64: encoded,
    s3Signature: signature
  };

  GLOBAL.s3creds = s3Credentials;

  callback(s3Credentials);
};
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, here. But I have no idea what. Can anyone help identify what I'm doing wrong? Where my problem is? **Does anyone have a working tutorial for how to generate a proper Amazon S3 Policy, with signature, from NodeJS v0.10.x, for a POST to the s3 REST api?**

Comment: Uploading a file directly to S3 is not really a trivial task, especially if you want to support chunking, auto-resume, user metadata, etc, etc.  The policy stuff _can_ be quite complex.  Consider using a library I maintain: [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com).  It has native support for direct uploads to S3 in all browsers, even IE7.  Chunking and auto-resume, among other features, are also supported.  Furthermore, I wrote a [node.js server-side example](http://bit.ly/1do27a0) myself that, when paired with Fine Uploader S3, will handle all signatures for you.

Comment: can you post this comment as an answer? i may end up using your library. still evaluating how it works, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure that will go over well.  It may be considered a poor or link-only answer, quite frankly.  My understanding is that the community is looking for details answers that include code, and mine doesn't fit that description, which is why I posted it as a comment.  If you do have any questions about Fine Uploader, have a look at the fine-uploader tag on SO though, where we handle support questions for the library.

Comment: @RayNicholus I have been researching "browser direct to s3" uploads using AWS for a little bit now and arrived to this thread. The two methods I have tried are `getSignedUrl()` which is dead simple, and this form POST method which is much more complicated but a lot more configurable. I glanced over your lib and I noticed it uses the s3 REST API is that correct? Does this have anything to do with Cognito?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out. After playing the random guessing game for a VERY long time, I thought to myself

> "maybe i need to sign the base64 encoded policy" - me

and **BAM** that was it.

I also re-ordered the conditions to match how the form is posting, though I'm not sure this makes a difference.

```
var crypto = require("crypto");
var config = require("../../amazonConfig.json");

exports.createS3Policy = function(contentType, callback) {
  var date = new Date();

  var s3Policy = {
    "expiration": "2014-12-01T12:00:00.000Z", // hard coded for testing
    "conditions": [
      ["starts-with", "$key", "somefolder/"], 
      {"bucket": "my-bucket-name"}, 
      {"acl": "public-read"}, 
      ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", contentType],
      {"success_action_redirect": "http://example.com/uploadsuccess"},
    ]
  };

  // stringify and encode the policy
  var stringPolicy = JSON.stringify(s3Policy);
  var base64Policy = Buffer(stringPolicy, "utf-8").toString("base64");

  // sign the base64 encoded policy
  var signature = crypto.createHmac("sha1", config.secretKey)
    .update(new Buffer(base64Policy, "utf-8")).digest("base64");

  // build the results object
  var s3Credentials = {
    s3Policy: base64Policy,
    s3Signature: signature
  };

  // send it back
  callback(s3Credentials);
};
```

Hopefully this will help others that run in to the same problem.

Comment: THANK YOU! This code helped me out. Some quick comments: To format the date I used [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) like so : `moment.utc(expirationDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'T'+moment.utc(expirationDate).format('HH:mm:ss.SSS')+'Z'`. Also for buffers 'utf8' (note: no hyphen) is default encoding so I think "utf-8" is incorrect and extraneous.

Comment: @Zugwalt, you could simplify that quite a bit with moment's built in formatting. `moment.utc(expirationDate).toISOString()`

Comment: Not sure why this one is failing but I do get "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." errors. So I tried using the example of @scabbiaza and that one did work. So I assume your code example is no longer working.

Answer (score 19):

I modified a bit previous example, because it didn't work for me: amazon returned an error about broken signature.

Here is how the signature should be created for Browser-Based Uploads Using POST (AWS Signature Version 4)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html

[image: Calculating a Signature]

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

var accessKeyID = "PUT YOUR DATA";
var secretAccessKey = "PUT YOUR DATA";

var bucket = "PUT YOUR BUCKET NAME";
var region = "eu-central-1"; // overwrite with your region
var folder = "users/"; // overwrite with your folder
var expiration = "2015-09-28T12:00:00.000Z"; // overwrite date
var date = "20150927"; // overwrite date
var serviceName = "s3";


function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
   var kDate = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dateStamp, "AWS4" + key);
   var kRegion = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
   var kService = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
   var kSigning = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("aws4_request", kService);

   return kSigning;
}

var s3Policy = {"expiration": expiration,
  "conditions": [
   {"bucket": bucket},
   ["starts-with", "$key", folder],
   {"acl": "public-read"},
   ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
   {"x-amz-meta-uuid": "14365123651274"},
   ["starts-with", "$x-amz-meta-tag", ""],
   {"x-amz-credential": accessKeyID + "/" + date + "/" + region + "/" + serviceName +"/aws4_request"},
   {"x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
   {"x-amz-date": date + "T000000Z" }
  ]
};

var base64Policy = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(s3Policy), "utf-8").toString("base64");
console.log('base64Policy:', base64Policy);

var signatureKey = getSignatureKey(secretAccessKey, date, region, serviceName);
var s3Signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(base64Policy, signatureKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
console.log('s3Signature:', s3Signature);
```

Next generated base64Policy and s3Signature i used in the form for uploading.
Example is here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

Very important is to check that you have the same fields and values in the html form and in your policy.

Answer (score 3):

I continued to have issues, so I worked through them and posted my solution here:

https://github.com/nikkwong/ng2-s3-uploader

In short, if you go with scabbiaza's answer in building the signature, make sure to build the form like so:

```
let formData = new FormData;
formData.append('acl', xAmzAcl);
formData.append('Content-Type', file.type);
formData.append('X-Amz-Date', xAmzDate);
formData.append('x-amz-server-side-encryption', xAmzServerSideEncryption);
formData.append('x-amz-meta-uuid', xAmzMetaUuid);
formData.append('X-Amz-Algorithm', xAmzAlgorithm);
formData.append('X-Amz-Credential', xAmzCredential);
formData.append('X-Amz-Signature', s3Signature);
formData.append('Policy', base64Policy);
formData.append('key', folder + '/' + file.name);
// File field must come last! 
formData.append('file', file);
```

Answer (score 1):

AWS SDK now provides an easy way to create the POST policy with `createPresignedPost()`.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property