# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when PUTting to S3

Tags: ajax, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I am PUTting files to S3 via ajax requests and about 50% of the time I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors.

I know the requests are signed correctly -- any ideas what may be causing this?  Again, this is an intermittent problem that I see from multiple locations and machines.

Here is the relevant coffeescript code I am using to PUT my files to S3.  It is derived from Micah Roberson's and Rok Krulec's work at http://micahroberson.com/upload-files-directly-to-s3-w-backbone-on-heroku/ and http://codeartists.com/post/36892733572/how-to-directly-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-your.

```
  createCORSRequest: (method, url) ->
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

    if xhr.withCredentials?
      xhr.open method, url, true
    else if typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"
      xhr = new XDomainRequest()
      xhr.open method, url
    else
      xhr = null

    xhr

  uploadToS3: (file, signature) ->
    this_s3upload = this
    this_s3upload.signature = signature
    url = signature.signed_request

    xhr = @createCORSRequest 'PUT', decodeURIComponent(signature.signed_request)

    if !xhr
      @onError 'CORS not supported'
    else
      xhr.onload = () ->
        if xhr.status == 200
          this_s3upload.onProgress 100, 'Upload completed.'
          this_s3upload.onFinishS3Put file, this_s3upload.signature
        else
          this_s3upload.onError file, 'Upload error: ' + xhr.status

      xhr.onerror = () ->
        this_s3upload.onError file, 'XHR error.', this_s3upload.signature

      xhr.upload.onprogress = (e) ->
        if e.lengthComputable
          percentLoaded = Math.round (e.loaded / e.total) * 100

          if percentLoaded == 100
            message = "Finalizing"
          else
            message = "Uploading"

          this_s3upload.onProgress xhr, file, percentLoaded, message, this_s3upload.signature

      xhr.onabort = ->
        this_s3upload.onAbort file, "XHR cancelled by user.", this_s3upload.signature

    xhr.setRequestHeader 'Content-Type', file.type
    xhr.setRequestHeader 'x-amz-acl', 'public-read'
    xhr.send file
```

**Update**

I've been getting very attentive support from Amazon on this issue.  Per their suggestion, I created an EC2 Windows instance, loaded the Chrome browser on it, and attempted to upload 5 files 10 times with my code.  I did not see the error once.  I did see some SignatureDoesNotMatch errors occasionally, but not a single ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error.  I am still seeing ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors though on every non-EC2 client/network location I use.

**Update** Still no solution here.  I have moved from using a self-rolled signing algorithm to one provided by boto.  No impact on the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET issue though.

Comment: If someone else is having this same problem, I would appreciate knowing I am not alone.  ;)

Comment: I'm having the same problem! I'm using the same set of resources (the blog and model code), and having the exact same result. About half the time, the request gives ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with no other information.

Comment: Thanks Joan.  I have an active question in with AWS, but it requires me to replicate my browser code as a stand-alone process for them to debug -- which requires some development.

Comment: Let me know if you want help putting something together for AWS. The sooner I get this straightened out, the better. I'd be happy to work with you on github (or alternative), if that would be useful.

Comment: Just wanted to add a +1. I'm experiencing the same issue, having largely followed [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python) for downloading from a Angular/coffeescript front end for my Django app.

Comment: Update added -- no errors when using an EC2 instance as a client.

Comment: I've also been experiencing this (for about 9 months to a year?). I haven't found a solution. :-/

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue when uploading bigger files (long requests) with pre-signed URLs, following [Heroku's example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node) (node aws sdk) :

```
app.get('/sign-s3', (req, res) => {
  const s3 = new aws.S3();
  const fileName = req.query['file-name'];
  const fileType = req.query['file-type'];
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
    Key: fileName,
    Expires: 60,
    ContentType: fileType,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  };

  s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
      return res.end();
    }
    const returnData = {
      signedRequest: data,
      url: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${fileName}`
    };
    res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
    res.end();
  });
});
```

The "Expires" parameter makes the signed URL valid for 60 seconds.

I figured the request crashes when the signed URL expires in the middle of upload (even though it was valid when upload started).

It doesn't crash exactly after 60 seconds though, but randomly between 60 and 120 seconds. Most of the time, the client logs ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, and other times it logs 403 FORBIDDEN.

After cranking it up to 3600 I had no issues anymore.

I suspect the issue didn't happen on EC2s because they have very fast upload speeds.

Answer (score 1):

I finally gave up on getting this to work.  Instead, I am now using [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/) to provide this functionality.

Comment: Which is no longer in business :-(

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this problem has no decision.

Try a POST request: https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

```
<form action="https://s3-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="uploads/${filename}">
  <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="http://localhost/">
  <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="YOUR_POLICY_DOCUMENT_BASE64_ENCODED">
  <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="YOUR_CALCULATED_SIGNATURE">
  <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg">
  <!-- Include any additional input fields here -->

  File to upload to S3: 
  <input name="file" type="file"> 
  <br> 
  <input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3"> 
</form>
```

Use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to append fields, if you prefer AJAX sending

To sign a request in nodejs: [Amazon S3 POST api, and signing a policy with NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476217/amazon-s3-post-api-and-signing-a-policy-with-nodejs)