# Access Denied when trying to do Browser-Based Upload using HTTP POST (Using AWS Signature Version 4)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cryptography

I am using these resources to try and get this working:

- [This question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476217/amazon-s3-post-api-and-signing-a-policy-with-nodejs)
- The official [Amazon HTTP POST example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html).
- The [Amazon HTTP POST documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html).

I am trying to upload a file to my s3 bucket by signing a form. I have cut down my form and policy to only the most basic required options as per the documentation and I still get "AccessDenied". Currently dates are hard-coded for simplicity.

### Code in my ExpressJS Router

```
var accessKeyID = credentials.accessKeyId;
var secretAccessKey = credentials.secretAccessKey;

var bucket = 'images.mybucket.com';
var region = 'us-east-1';
var expiration = '2016-11-28T12:00:00.000Z';
var date = '20161108';
var serviceName = 's3';
var credentialUrl = accessKeyID + '/' + date + '/' + region + '/' + serviceName + '/aws4_request';
var amazonDate = '20161108T000000Z';

var s3Policy = {
    'expiration': expiration,
    'conditions': [
        {'bucket': bucket},
        ['starts-with', '$key', 'UserUploads/'],
        {'acl': 'public-read'},
        {'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256'},
        {'x-amz-credential': credentialUrl},
        {'x-amz-algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'},
        {'x-amz-date': amazonDate}
    ]
};

var base64Policy = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(s3Policy), 'utf-8').toString('base64');

var signatureKey = getSignatureKey(secretAccessKey, date, region, serviceName);

var s3Signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(base64Policy, signatureKey).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {        
    var kDate = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(dateStamp, 'AWS4' + key);
    var kRegion = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(regionName, kDate);
    var kService = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(serviceName, kRegion);
    var kSigning = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256('aws4_request', kService);
    return kSigning;
}
```

### HTML

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<form action="http://images.mybucket.com.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>key to upload</p>
    <input type="input" name="key" value="UserUploads/${filename}">
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read">
    <input type="hidden" name="x-amz-server-side-encryption" value="AES256">
    <input type="text" name="X-Amz-Credential" value="REDACTED-access-key-id/20161108/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request">
    <input type="text" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256">
    <input type="text" name="X-Amz-Date" value="20161108T000000Z">
    <p>tags for file</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="REDACTED-base64-encoded-policy">
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="REDACTED-signature">
    <p>file</p>
    <input type="file" name="file"><input type="submit" value="Upload File to S3">
</form>
```

Comment: I may be leading you in the wrong direction, but there are constraints in Signature Version 4 that *may* prevent anything with an expiration date more than 7 × 24 hours in the future from being considered valid, though it apparently isn't mentioned in the context of form post uploads. Setting your expiration to a time only a few hours in the future *may* be more appropriate than the 20 days shown in this code.  Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: I set it to a few hours in the future. No dice.

Comment: Is there nothing in the response body accompanying the error?

Comment: This is the body of the response:    <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>61A311EC384705FA</RequestId>
<HostId>
n3hmQu2rAJF5+tKjYdS7CtUcgQX7kpqGtfdFD1Ylma/JVhASngvET/O+r0Z528rrayWj2ddmkqY=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: I think this is an IAM issue. When I grant my credentials the AdministrtorAccess policy everything suddenly works. My putObject is set up correctly and I am able to upload with the S3 browser.

Answer (score 0):

The permission `s3:PutObjectAcl` is required because in your bucket policy, you're setting the acl via `"acl": "public-read"`.